# How to compute the gate matrix for an operation on qubits not next to each other

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, matrix-representation

I have a quantum circuit with 4 input qubits, A, B, C, and D. A is at the top, D is at the bottom.

If I wanted to do a CNOT between B and C and leave A and D alone, I know the gate matrix for this would be computed as $$I \otimes CNOT \otimes I$$ where $I$ is the 2x2 identity matrix, $CNOT$ is the controlled not gate matrix, and $\otimes$ is tensor product.

But how do I compute the gate matrix if I want to CNOT A and D and leave B and C alone?

I've looked at [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34996/can-you-apply-a-cnot-gate-on-qubits-in-mbqc-that-aren%C2%B4t-next-to-each-other) and it seems close, but the MBQC terminology seems to be confusing everyone (including me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give an example of three qubits because I am lazy to writing out things for four qubits, but you should get the idea.

Assume you have three qubits, qubits $A, B$ and $C$. You perform a $\text{CNOT}$ from qubit $A$ to $C$. So what is the matrix representation of $\text{CNOT}_{A \to C}$?

#### Step 1:

Write out what happens to all computational basis states under this operation.

$$\begin{align}
|000\rangle \to |000\rangle \\
|001\rangle \to |001\rangle \\
|100\rangle \to |101\rangle \\
|101\rangle \to |100\rangle \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
|010\rangle \to |010\rangle \\
|011\rangle \to |011\rangle \\
|110\rangle \to |111\rangle \\
|111\rangle \to |110\rangle \\
\end{align}$$

#### Step 2:

Take the sum over the outer product between all these initial and final states, and that will give you your required matrix, wherein the outer product, *bra* part is the initial state, and the *ket* part is the final state after the action of your operation.

$$\begin{align}
\text{CNOT}_{A \to C} &=  |000\rangle \langle 000| +|001\rangle \langle 001| +|101\rangle \langle 100| +|100\rangle \langle 101|\\
&+ |010\rangle \langle 010| +|011\rangle \langle 011| +|111\rangle \langle 110| +|110\rangle \langle 111| \,.\\
\end{align}$$

---

#### General case:

If you have a quantum operation $M$ which maps a set of orthogonal states $\{ |i\rangle \}$ to another set of orthogonal states $\{ |j\rangle \}$, then the matrix representation of $M$ can be written as follows
$$M = \sum_{i,j} |j\rangle \langle i|\,.$$

---

#### Why this works?

Let's take an example so things will be clear. What should happen to, say state $|101\rangle$ under the action of $\text{CNOT}_{A \to C}$? It should go to  $|100\rangle\,.$ So let's see -

$$\begin{align}
\text{CNOT}_{A \to C} |101\rangle &=  \bigg(|000\rangle \langle 000| +|001\rangle \langle 001| +|101\rangle \langle 100| +|100\rangle \langle 101|\\
&+ |010\rangle \langle 010| +|011\rangle \langle 011| +|111\rangle \langle 110| +|110\rangle \langle 111|\bigg)|101\rangle\,.
\end{align}$$

Here, you can see that all terms in the summation except the term with $|101\rangle$ as *bra* part will go to zero since they are all orthogonal states. The only term which survives is

$$\text{CNOT}_{A \to C} |101\rangle = |100\rangle \underbrace{ \langle 101|101\rangle}_{= 1}\,.$$

Hence, you get
$$\text{CNOT}_{A \to C} |101\rangle = |100\rangle\,.$$

Since we start with a set of orthogonal initial states, for a given initial state, the only term in the summation which would be non-zero would be the one which as the *bra* part of that initial state. The *bra* and *ket* of the initial state will go to 1, and you will always be left with the appropriate final state.

---

##### How to do this process efficiently? A short-cut

For your case, you will need a $16 \times 16$ matrix. Each column from left to right corresponds to the basis states $0,1,\cdots 15$ in binary. Just replace the appropriate column to the resultant state under your $\text{CNOT}_{A \to D}$ operation—no need to perform 16 outer products and then do the addition.

Example- $|1001\rangle$ should go to $|1000\rangle$. So place the $9^{\text{th}}$ coloumn$^1$ in your matrix $\big( (1001)_2 = (9)_{10 } \big)\,,$ with state vector for the resultant state  $|1000\rangle\,.$

This should save a lot of computation, whenever your initial states are computational basis states.

---

<sup>$^1$: Here, I am labeling coloumns of $16 \times 16$ matrix from $0$ to $15$.</sup>

Comment: Nice answer!!!!!

Comment: @Saul_better Thank you.